# Compositum and intersection of number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that we have three number fields $K,L$ and $M$. Assume that all of these number fields are Galois and that $M$ is abelian (for the sake of brevity we may assume that it is Cyclotomic).

**Edit:** Is it true that $KL \cap M= (K\cap M)(L\cap M)$ ?

I believe that this need not be true in general but I am not able to come up with a counter-example.

Comment: $K=L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected a typo.

Comment: $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ is a counterexample.